# Continuously Rotate Image OnTouchEvent In Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm new to Android development and am trying to figure out how to continuously rotate an image using the onTouchEvent.  I am using the following code to rotate the image 10 degrees when the onTouchEvent detects a screen touch and vice versa, but I want the image to keep rotating in 10 degree intervals as long as the onTouchEvent occurs.  Thanks!

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            degrees=degrees+10;
            make(degrees);
            }
        else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            degrees=degrees-10;
            make(degrees);
            }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, is you want to start rotating an image when the user puts his / her finger on the screen, and stop rotating when the user takes off the finger from the screen.

If that's correct, you'd need to start a thread or a handler on the background that would keep.

May be something like:

```
// flag to tell if the rotation should continue
private boolean keepRotating = false;
// instance variable to keep the current rotation degrees
private int degrees = 0;
// rotation interval in milliseconds
private static final int INTERVAL = 100;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    switch (event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startRotating();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            stopRotating();
            break;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void startRotating()
{
    if (!keepRotating)
    {
        keepRotating = true;

        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                if (keepRotating)
                {
                    degrees = (degrees + 10) % 360;
                    make(degrees);

                    handler.postDelayed(this, INTERVAL);
                }
            }
        }, INTERVAL);
    }
}

public void stopRotating()
{
    keepRotating = false;
}

public void make(int degrees)
{
    Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Rotation : " + degrees);

    // Your rotation logic here based on the degrees parameter
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That is correct, I want the image to continuously rotate when the screen is touched and stop rotating when the touch event is ended.

Comment: I'm not sure if this was the correct manner to reverse the rotation, but I added a 'returnRotating' variable to the startRotating() and StopRotating() sections to make the needle return to it's original position like so:    

  public void stopRotating()
    {
     keepRotating = false;
        if (!returnRotating)
    //...

Comment: Ammm, You mean you want the needle to return to its original location before starting the next lap or something? Like if i start, and then stop the needle. And after that start it again, it should start from 0 instead of continuing from where it was stopped. Correct? For this using returnRotating boolean should be fine. But that all depends on your requirement and the logic :)

Comment: Thanks Sharique.  I was able to resolve the return feature of my activity as stated above.  I am currently having problems making the activity display in the correct location as I still do not fully understand layouts, but I'm working to resolve that issue as well

Comment: The Android documentation has very detailed information about layouts, you can Google about it, you'll get to it easily. However once you understand, layouts are the best thing someone can get for UI design. They are just awesome. Much better than pretty much anything else you get these days.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
degrees = (degrees + 10) % 360;

// ...

if(degrees < 10) degrees += 360;
degrees = (degrees - 10) % 360;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
public void startMoving() {
    rotateAnimation1 = null;
    try {
        if (duration < 1500) {
            rotateAnimation1 = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            rotateAnimation1.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            rotateAnimation1.setDuration(duration);
            rotateAnimation1.setRepeatCount(0);
            imgBottle.startAnimation(rotateAnimation1);

            flagSpinAvailable = false;

            rotateAnimation1.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim) {
                };

                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim) {
                };

                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
                    duration = duration + 70;
                    startMoving();
                };
            });

        } else {
            duration = duration + 100;
            final float degree = (float) (Math.random() * 360);
            degreeBack = 360 - degree;
            rotateAnimation2 = new RotateAnimation(0, degree,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            rotateAnimation2.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            rotateAnimation2.setDuration(duration);
            rotateAnimation2.setRepeatCount(0);
            rotateAnimation2.setFillAfter(true);
            imgBottle.startAnimation(rotateAnimation2);

            rotateAnimation2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim) {
                };

                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim) {
                };

                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
                    afterSpinEnd();
                };
            });

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        flagSpinAvailable = true;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my code to rotate a image around itself and slowly decrease the speed